# Error with certification validation when cloning repo from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, repo

I tried to clone the Azure DevOps repository into the Visual Studio 2022 and I came across some errors that is difficult to workaround and figure out. Although my PAT is properly synched with GitHub and the connection still works but it continues to throw fatal error, which is confusing.

Regards,
Asim Khan

[Cloning in Visual Studio 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LuaF.png)

[Fatal Certification Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si3mP.png)

[GitHub Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL1wU.png)

I did the following operations:

- Opened Visual Studio 2022
- Clicked on clone repo
- Opened Azure DevOps option
- Selected the required repo
- Clicked on connect
- Error thrown

Comment: I fixed the issue for the fata error for missing certificates files and folders, turns out that the certification files and the folders were missing. Found the necessary files and folders and placed it in the right location to find the certificates.

But even after the repo has been cloned, the development branch is not showing up from the repo in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.